# How to search for type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm still learning typescript, but types make me struggle a little bit, for example, a typescript interface look like this

```
interface FooInterface {
  randomNumber?: string;
  randomWidth?: number;
  someStyle?: CSS.Properties;
  someJSX?:JSX.Element;

}
```

My question is, where can i find doc for advance type like `CSS.Properties` or `someJSX?:JSX.Element`, I search the doc, but i find nothing, i mean, how can we know css will use `css.properties`?? Is there any website list all of typescript type and when to use them?? Like `JSX.Element` for React component type?

So my question is, **how can i find all typescript type or any website list all types avaliable? or simply, how can i know which type i gonna need? For example i want variable X to be a function, which type can i define X ?**

Please help, thank you a lot

Comment: If your editor is VS Code or some variation, you can simply cmd/ctrl+click on the type to go to its type definition. You should be able to repeat this for all type aliases all the way down to primitives.

Comment: Yes, but it only in case i know which type, but my problem is i did'nt know why type to use

Comment: I think you should get started by reading [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript comes bundled with type definitions for DOM APIs, such as that CSS namespace. These types are generated from this repo: [TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator)

You don't need to understand anything about that repo in order to use TypeScript though. If you're not sure how to work with a particular DOM API, I recommend looking it up on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).

For non-native APIs (for example React, which I guess your example was using given the presence of `JSX.Element`), there are type definitions made available through the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project. These types are typically installed as dev dependencies using a package manager like npm, where they exist under the namespace `@types`, for example [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react).

Generally, you won't need to know all the ins and outs of how all these types are defined. The type definitions exist to assist you in using these APIs by providing tooltips and autocomplete, as well as TypeScript's general type safety. Where you do need to understand them, for example when you're working with a particular typed library, that library likely provides its own documentation that you can check.

Generally you'll most likely encounter these types when working with values returned by API methods. For example, if I am working with a variable with the type `CSSStyleDeclaration`, I probably got it by calling `window.getComputedStyle`. If I have an `HTMLElement`, I probably got it through a DOM API method like `document.createElement` or `document.getElementById`.

I don't think `CSS.Properties` is actually an available type or an interface, unless your example has created something with that name. It sounds like it's just meant as an example though.

Comment: That `CSS.Properties` may be this interface https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/6efe9255f529786fbe37405fc608fb885eef67e1/index.d.ts#L8810 in [csstype](https://github.com/frenic/csstype) package.

Comment: You make younger by 10 years, thank a lots